# Should this question be marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

This recent question was asked: [QGIS snap question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245965/qgis-snap-question) which has been marked as a duplicate of this: [Aligning multiple points to line in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237224/aligning-multiple-points-to-line-in-qgis).

However, the duplicated post contains only one solution but **for a future software version**. This solution does not seem to be available in a stable release yet.

Should this question be marked as a duplicate if the solution mentioned may not be easily accessible?

Comment: Yes, the question is a duplicate of the earlier question.  If there is a possible more relevant answer it should be answered on the original not on the new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - if both questions are the same then they are duplicate questions irrespective of any answers.

Ignoring the "next release" answer, an answer in the current release to the original will also provide an answer to the duplicate.

Duplicates work this way so that attention is focused on attracting answers to the original question rather than having answers scattered among duplicates.